# Reverse the contents of array of n elements

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, reverse

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[100],n,i;
    printf("Enter the number of elements you want to enter in any array:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter the elements you want to enter in the array:\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    
    printf("Array:\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\nReversed order:\n");

    
for(i=n;i>=0;i--)
    {
        printf("\n %d",a[i]);
    }
}
```

What is the mistake in my code? This code is not completely correct. Please tell me where I am making mistake. I am not getting reverse of the array properly so there must be mistake in this part:

```
for(i=n;i>=0;i--)
        {
            printf("\n %d",a[i]);
        }
```

Comment: FWIW, you are not reversing anything except the printing order.

Comment: Your mistake is that you are starting from index `n`, which is one past the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop

```
for(i=n;i>=0;i--)
{
    printf("\n %d",a[i]);
}
```

when `i` is initially equal to `n` then you are trying to output an uninitialized elements of the array because the range of indices of initialized elements is `[0, n)`.

You could rewrite the loop like

```
for ( i = n; i != 0; )
{
    printf("\n %d",a[--i]);
}
```

or

```
for ( i = n; i != 0; i-- )
{
    printf("\n %d",a[i - 1]);
}
```

But in any case the program does not reverse an array (or a sub-array). It outputs an array in the reverse order.

To reverse an array you need to write

```
for ( i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
{
    int tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[n - i - 1];
    a[n - i - 1] = tmp;
}
```

and then to output the reversed array like

```
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    printf("\n %d",a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only read values to `a[i]` where `i<n`.

`a[n]` is not initialized, so you shouldn't use the value.

The final loop should start from `i=n-1`, not `i=n`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not reverse the array only try to display the array in reverse order.

To reverse the array you need to swap elements.

```
int *reverse(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    int *head = arr, *end = arr + size - 1;

    if(arr && size > 1)
    {
        while(end > head)
        {
            int temp = *head;
            *head++ = *end;
            *end-- = temp;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stated objective: to *Reverse the contents of array of n elements*

> *"What is the mistake in my code?"*

Two items:

- overwriting array bounds in loop
- failing to populate the contents of an array in reverse order

1. C by convention uses zero based array indexing, so for an array of `n` elements, the only time the value `n` is used within the array brackets `[.]`is during declaration.

```
     int n= 10;
     int array[n] = {0};//n used to size the array to exactly n elements
```

All other times the value `n-1` is the maximum value owned by the array. Due to zero based array indexing, the range of values are 0 to n-1.  For this statement then, the very first iteration, with `i == n`, the array index attempts to access memory it does not own:

```
    for(i=n;i>=0;i--)
    {
        printf("\n %d",a[i]);
        ...              ^  i == n writes to memory location not owned by process.  UB
```

Change the for loop:  `for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)`

2. A [simple algorithm to reverse the contents of an array](https://www.google.com/search?q=simple+algorithm+to+reverse+array+in+C&client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ALiCzsZjPcKhRCMMn0Y7Z9D9RB4j6-TUDg%3A1658864688988&ei=METgYsb6O72w0PEPzJKwkAw&ved=0ahUKEwjG0pHEqJf5AhU9GDQIHUwJDMIQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=simple+algorithm+to+reverse+array+in+C&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABOgcIABBHELADOgcIABCwAxBDOgQIABBDOgUIABCABDoHCAAQgAQQCjoECAAQCjoKCAAQgAQQhwIQFDoGCAAQHhAWOgUIABCGAzoFCCEQqwI6CAghEB4QFhAdSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUIcQWN4xYOo0aAFwAXgAgAG0AYgBjg2SAQQyMS4xmAEAoAEByAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) follows: (in pseudo code).

   ```
   temp = arr[i]
   arr[i] = arr[n - i - 1]  
   arr[n - i - 1] = temp
   ```